# Connect a music player in SIP voice call

Tags: vlc-media-player, voip, asterisk, sip

I need to establish a normal Voip conversation between 2 persons and one of them, using a softphone in Windows, insert audio from a music player which can be controlled by the own user.

The voip server is Asterisk. Maybe do a conference between the users and one of them, using a Windows PC, configure a music player (like VLC) to act as a third party in the conference.

I have investigated the RTP capabilities of VLC, Music on Hold of the Asterisk.

The purpose of the music player is to play a voice record and thus there is no problem with low quality music in the voice channel.

Can you please give ideas to do it?

Thanks :-)

joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple softphones support this: baresip, tSIP, pjsua. You can also use virtual audio devices, virtual audio mixers or even physical audio mixers.

Comment: Thanks! :-) You replied with a simple but compreensive answer. Specifically, the users are Windows users familiar with graphic interfaces and both baresip and pjsua are command line based and tSIP requires audio file in specific format that the user should convert. But the virtual audio devices is the perfect solution: i have total control of the audio (back, forward, pause, etc) with a generic music player connected as the third user in the call. Thanks a lot!